# Освобождение памяти в С++

Tags: c++

Предположим есть указатель на другой указатель. Я меняю значение этого указателя (например, на nullptr). Вопрос: очищается ли память, выделенная под другой указатель?

Comment: Нет, с чего бы это она начала очищаться?

Comment: В языке Си/C++ программисту все надо делать самому и явно. И занимать память (в куче) и очищать память. Если же вопрос об объектах не в куче, то ответ такой же - языке Си/C++ САМО (почти)ничего не делается, все надо делать программисту.

Answer (score 0):

Обнуление (как и любое другое изменение) значений обычных «сырых» указателей в c++ не приводит к какому-либо освобождению памяти, на которую они указывают. Но совершенно свободно могут привести к утечке памяти. Обычный указатель легковесен, он не обладает какими-то скрытыми возможностями для управления адресованной им памятью. Представляйте указатель как обычный простой адрес памяти и всё будет ясно. Уничтожение письма с адресом не приводит к уничтожению дома, расположенного по этому адресу. Таким образом говорить о том, чтобы изменение значения указателя влияло на память — нельзя, а уж при добавлении еще одного косвенного указателя тем более. Если нужно освободить динамически выделенную через `new`/`new[]` память по указателю, следует использовать соответствующий оператор: `delete` для скалярных величин или `delete[]` для массивов. Более того, даже после освобождения памяти сам указатель никак не изменяется и не обнуляется автоматически. Если нужно его пометить свободным после удаления, требуется вручную присвоить ему новое значение, например, тот же самый `nullptr`.

Если нужно, чтобы изменение значения указателя влияло на память, адресуемую этим указателем, он должен быть нечто большим, чем просто адресом. В частности для этого придумали «умные» указатели — классы-обёртки, в функциях (и конструкторах/деструкторах в особенности) которых реализовано необходимое дополнительное поведение.

В стандартном c++ для этих целей существуют такие классы как `std::unique_ptr` и `std::shared_ptr`.